# How to clear a "stuck" job in Collabnet Edge

Tags: collabnet, subversion-edge

I'm having a problem with a job in collabnet edge. I created a blank repository, then did a load from a dump file. There was an issue during the load (finally figured out that I had run out of disk space) and due to this, a job got stuck.

So, here's what's happening:

- The load appeared to finish, the job isn't shown on the list.
- The data was not loaded correctly (no space...but took a while to figure that out)
- So I deleted the repository, added disk space and then tried to reload, but I get a message saying I can't because there is already a job running.

> A dump file is already set to be loaded. Only one load may be scheduled at a time; progress can be monitored on the Jobs screen.

As mentioned, there is no job listed as being in progress. The repo it was loading has been deleted.

How do I clear out this *stuck* job?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382891/resetting-subversion-backup-after-fail-due-to-running-out-of-disk-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there is a job progress for this repository logged under csvn/data/logs/temp

If present remove it and then re-schedule

Answer (score 2):

Check, if there is a file in the following directory:

> csvn/data/dumps/yourRepositoryName/load

Delete the file and then reload your dump-file.