# resetting subversion backup after fail due to running out of disk space

Tags: svn, subversion-edge

I am currently running an instance of subversion with collabnet subversion edge on top.

I had a nice backup routine which was interrupted by the drive it was being backed up to running out of space.

I have shut down the services and removed the temporary dump processing file. I remember last time this happened ages ago there was another temporary file I had to delete somewhere too.

What is the location and name of this file? I have been looking around for ages!

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look in the logs, you will find the following entry if you try to run another backup:

> 2015-07-13 14:30:00,047 [pool-4-thread-2] WARN  admin.RepoDumpJob  - Backup skipped: A backup for repo 'xxxxxxxxx' is already running, as indicated by prior existence of progress log 'C:\svn\data\logs\temp\job-progress-RepositaryName-dump.log'

You need to delete the file C:\svn\data\logs\temp\job-progress-RepositoryName-dump.log

Comment: That message can be found in the `console_...` log